# colgroup not working if parent is given width

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table which has a wrapper and scroll if table exceeds the width.
It works fine without giving width to parent.

I tried giving class to  still the result is same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-wrap">
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 350px"></col>
                <col style="width: 350px"></col>
                <col style="width: 350px"></col>
                <col style="width: 350px"></col>
                <col style="width: 350px"></col>
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                    <th>header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>one</td>
                    <td>one</td>
                    <td>one</td>
                    <td>one</td>
                    <td>one</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>one two</td>
                    <td>one two</td>
                    <td>one two</td>
                    <td>one two</td>
                    <td>one two</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>threeeee</td>
                    <td>threeeee</td>
                    <td>threeeee</td>
                    <td>threeeee</td>
                    <td>threeeee</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>cell one two</td>
                    <td>cell one two</td>
                    <td>cell one two</td>
                    <td>cell one two</td>
                    <td>cell one two</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

fiddle reference (http://jsfiddle.net/8xznsvyt/)

Comment: Include sufficient code (incl. CSS) in the question itself. Clearly state *how* things fail and make sure the code you post really causes that. Specify the browser(s) tested, with version numbers. Explain why you think `colgroup` markup is relevant; it seems to be completely redundant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to have a table with 5 columns, all 350px wide, wrapped inside a container that has width set on it. And you would want the table scroll horizontally if the container is narrower than needed for the table.

What happens in the fiddle is that the table is as wide as the container. This is a consequence of [CSS table formatting](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout) rules. Consequently, the column width settings cannot be fulfilled. Browsers apply dynamic column allocation instead, dividing the available width between the columns according to their content requirements (in the fiddle, evenly, since the contents are identical).

The simplest fix is to set a width on the table explicitly:

```css
col {
  width: 350px;
}
table {
  width: 1756px; /* 5 × 350 + 6, for columns and borders */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.table-wrap {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
    <table>
      <col><col><col><col><col>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>header</th>
                <th>header</th>
                <th>header</th>
                <th>header</th>
                <th>header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>one</td>
                <td>one</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>one two</td>
                <td>one two</td>
                <td>one two</td>
                <td>one two</td>
                <td>one two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>threeeee</td>
                <td>threeeee</td>
                <td>threeeee</td>
                <td>threeeee</td>
                <td>threeeee</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cell one two</td>
                <td>cell one two</td>
                <td>cell one two</td>
                <td>cell one two</td>
                <td>cell one two</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have simplified the HTML and CSS code somewhat. There is no need for the `colspan` element; it is neither part of the problem nor part of a solution. The column widths are best set in CSS